# Solve for $x\in\mathbb{R}$: $x^{2} + 2|x-3| - 10 \leq 0$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I went about taking cases for $x^{2} + 2|x-3|- 10\leq 0$.

Taking $x-3$ and $-(x-3)$ as cases. Is it the correct approach?

Taking cases I realise I get $x^{2} + 2x - 16 \leq 0$ and $x^{2}-2x-4 \leq 0$.

How would I take intersection of solutions here?

Comment: Yes, this would generate all solutions.

Comment: @Landuros but that generates x²+2x-16 =<0 and x²-2x-4 =< 0 that don't factor out, so how would I take the intersection? Would the solution in this case be a null set?

Comment: Saying "Taking x-3 and -(x-3) as cases" is not very rigorous. If you add rigor, the solution will become obvious.

Comment: @Techie5879 Have you come across the quadratic formula before? Solve for solutions of $x$ using that and then look for the regions where the graphs are greater than zero. That is your solution set.

Comment: @YvesDaoust how do you suggest so?

Comment: @Techie5879: $x-3$ is not a "case".

Comment: @Landuros yes I have, ok thanks

Comment: @YvesDaoust $$|x-3|=x-3$$ IS a case. It's the same thing as saying $x\geq 3$ but that's beside the point

Comment: @JulianMejia careful, its $(x+1)^2-17$.

Comment: @Rhys oh, thanks, i'll edit.

Comment: 1st case: $x>3$, your inequality becomes $x^2+2x-16\leq 0$, which is the same as $(x+1)^2-17\leq 0$, i.e. $(x+1+\sqrt{17})(x+1-\sqrt{17})\leq 0$. Solve this inequality and intersect it with $x>3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the following way.

We need to solve
$$2|x-3|\leq10-x^2,$$ which is
$$-(10-x^2)\leq2(x-3)\leq10-x^2,$$ which is
$$x^2+2x-16\leq0$$ and
$$x^2-2x-4\leq0,$$ which is
$$-1-\sqrt{17}\leq x\leq-1+\sqrt{17}$$ and
$$1-\sqrt{5}\leq x\leq1+\sqrt5,$$ which gives the answer:
$$[1-\sqrt5,\sqrt{17}-1].$$

Answer (score 1):

For $$x\geq 3$$ we have to solve $$x^2+2(x-3)-10\le 0$$ this is fulfiiled for $$3\le x\le -1+\sqrt{17}$$
For $$x<3$$ we have to solve 
$$x^2-2(x-3)-10\le 0$$
this gives $$1-\sqrt{5}\le x<3$$